# Browser consuming too much RAM

Tags: memory

As you can see from the image my browser is consuming too much RAM. I disabled all the extensions and opened only one tab which is home. Is this normal for the browser to consume this much RAM? For my regular use, my browser consumes as much as 2GB of RAM. As I have 8GB RAM, I haven't felt any issue yet. But is there any way to reduce the amount of RAM consumption?

NB: I've tried other browsers like Chrome and Edge, but the situation is the same.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

Comment: 261 MB seems quite a low usage of RAM for a modern browser with a few open tabs - what pages are you loading?

Comment: That's not much at all. Modern browsers (and modern Web) can easily consume gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: I didn't open any tab other than home tab.

Comment: @BasilKuriakose The point is your assumption is wrong. It is NOT consuming too much RAM.

Comment: I have many these kinds of software, and some of them are the same as yours. I think it is normal. The software is running, it will has RAM.

Comment: Sites tend to be using more and more Javascript which also increases browser memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Firefox isn't using much RAM there, not on a machine with 8 GB RAM total. And what it is using is not a fixed number. If you run something else that needs a lot of RAM, Windows will shrink other processes to make room. (In fact, that's the answer to your question - how can you make Firefox use less RAM? Answer: Run something else that needs the RAM!)

Long version:

The "memory usage" of any process—or subset of processes—or the whole set of processes plus the OS—in any virtual memory OS is extremely dependent on the processes' behavior and on RAM pressure. That is, for any one process, it depends on how much RAM you have, what that process happens to be doing, and what other things you're running that are also need RAM at the moment.

Processes in a virtual memory OS do not actually demand or require or even ask for *any* amount of RAM (aside from some very small allocations set aside by the OS). Rather they request various amounts of *virtual memory*. In Windows this could be done by calling the `VirtualAlloc` Windows API, or by `malloc()` or `new()`, or `MapViewOfFile`; there are equivalents in the *nix environments.

These calls do not, in and of themselves, allocate any RAM to the process.

Later, as the process accesses locations within the allocated regions, the operating system allocates RAM to them on an "on demand" basis. (This is referred to as "paging on demand", and OSs that work this way are called "demand-paged" OSs.)

The OS will attempt to balance all of the processes' needs for RAM against each other. As long as there's plenty of free RAM (and given that you're showing 60% of your 8 GB free, you indeed have plenty), processes' RAM usage (called their "working sets") are allowed to grow pretty much without limit. But when free RAM gets too scarce, the OS has to start trimming processes back, forcing them to "page out" some of what they previously paged in. (The "pagefile" is sometimes involved here, but not always.)

So.. how much RAM a process occupies is not at all a fixed or even very predictable number. It is highly opportunistic, depending on the variables as described above.

Run your browser on the same sites on a system with more or less RAM, or with more or less other stuff running and demanding RAM, and the numbers will look very different.

Given that you are using only 40% of the RAM on an 8 GB system—leaving nearly 5 GB available—you don't have a problem. (I would point out that the amount you have available is more RAM than almost all personally owned machines had *total*, not very long ago!)

If you run something that needs more RAM than is currently available, Windows will trim back large processes, especially long-idle ones, to make room for the new thing. At about 250 MB I would not consider Firefox as shown in your screen cap to be particularly large.

If *that* isn't working, then we could say you have a problem.

Comment: You let one person live in an empty house, and he's going to use many of the rooms inefficiently, but who cares? When other people start moving into the other rooms, then he'll start putting his things away and using space efficiently. But needlessly doing extra work to use less RAM is inefficient and pointless when there's lots of free RAM, so sensible OSes don't do that. I have 32GB and half of it is free. My browser is using 6GB because there's no advantage to making it use less. Does it need 6GB? No.